# How to install apt-get on a busybox embedded system?

Tags: apt, busybox

My embedded system is for sh4 CPU.  The debian distribution may get on http://www.si-linux.co.jp/pub/debian-sh/lenny-sh4/

I get the apt*.deb and extract the data.tar.gz.
After setup the /etc/apt/sources.list, I could do 'apt-get update'.
But it missing dependency when I try to run 'apt-get install ntpdate'.
Is there any method to let apt-get ignore some base packages?
Because those package is build by my original embedded system.(eg. busybox).

Answer (score 1):

Does your system have "dpkg" installed? If so, installing the .deb package is as simple as:

```
dpkg -i my_package.deb
```

If dpkg is NOT installed, then I'm afraid this won't be a simple task, as apt-get depends on dpkg for most of its operations.

Comment: I think it is possible, if ar extract then tar extract then sh execute with proper parameter to simulate the work.